# Wordpress loop with different formating

Tags: php, wordpress

Instead of showing standard list of posts, i want to customize layout and divide posts into different (bootstrap) columns.
So, first post would be full width, bellow that second one would be half width and in other half i would show 3 more posts. Bellow that there would be 3 posts in a row.

I divided them like this:

```
<?php
// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'category_name' => 'cat_name',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 8
));
?>

<?php if ($the_query->have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php $count = 0; ?>
    <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php $count++; ?>

        <?php if ($count == 1) : ?>
            <div class="first"><?php the_title(); ?></div>

        <?php elseif ($count == 2) : ?>      
            <div class="second"><?php the_title(); ?></div>

        <?php elseif ($count >= 3 && $count <= 5) : ?>  
            <div class="third"><?php the_title(); ?></div>  

        <?php else : ?>
            <div class="fourth"><?php the_title(); ?></div>  

        <?php endif; ?>


    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php __('No News'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

but i dont know how to arrange them to appear like this:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <!-- first -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <!-- second -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <!-- third - 3 posts one under another -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <!-- fourth -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <!-- fourth -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <!-- fourth -->
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Any help would mean a lot!
I thought about using multiple queries with offset but I dont know would that be too much queries to DB (because this is only loop for 1 category, i would have 3 more bellow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. My first idea would be looping once through the posts, saving their titles (featured image, permalink, what ever you need) into an array and getting them in the markup by their indexes (starting with 0).

You could try it with arrays saving all the titles and permalinks:

```
<?php
    $post_titles = [];
    $post_permalinks = [];
    $counter = 0;
?>

<?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    $post_titles[$counter] = get_the_title($post->ID);
    $post_permalinks[$counter] = get_the_permalink($post->ID);
    $counter++;
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

And then you call the index of the array in your markup:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <?php echo $post_titles[0] . "<br>" . $post_permalinks[0]; ?>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <?php echo $post_titles[1] . "<br>" . $post_permalinks[1]; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <?php echo $post_titles[2] . "<br>" . $post_permalinks[2]; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <?php echo $post_titles[3] . "<br>" . $post_permalinks[3]; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <?php echo $post_titles[4] . "<br>" . $post_permalinks[4]; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <?php echo $post_titles[5] . "<br>" . $post_permalinks[5]; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <?php echo $post_titles[6] . "<br>" . $post_permalinks[6]; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <?php echo $post_titles[7] . "<br>" . $post_permalinks[7]; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @rank, thanks a bunch for helping out! I know i might be asking too much but i am new with php/wordpress, would you mind expanding it little more?

Comment: I'm happy to help! I updated my answer, hope this will guide you some more.

Comment: wow, really thanks a bunch! just so i am sure i havent messed something up (or if there is cleaner way to write it), is this it - https://jsfiddle.net/qw1p5u3f/

Comment: Glad you can make use of it, I think you will need something like:  <a href="<?php echo $post_permalinks[0]; ?>" title="<?php echo $post_titles[0]; ?>"><h2><?php echo $post_titles[0];?></h2></a><p><?php the_excerpt($post_ids[0]); ?></p>   See I added a new array with index? define a new empty array with the name post_ids. Then within the loop you set $post_ids[$counter] = get_the_ID($post->ID); and in your markup the the_excerpt() with the given id gets you the excerpt of your post. This way you can access all kind of data from the posts and display in freely choosen grid layout.

Comment: Yep, got it :) Lets say i want to show thumbnails, i would use $post_image = []; and then <?php $post_image[$counter] = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID); ?>.
But what if i need to show 3 different image sizes (called big, medium, small) in different columns? Would i need to create 3 different arrays for 3 different sizes and then show the one i want where i want or is there cleaner solution? Sorry for all the messages, i know im boring :D Hope all is great in Germany!

Comment: Yes, I think if you are not pretty experienced with php, taking your solution with 3 arrays is a very readable and easy to understand way doing this. Clean to read, and won't take more queries to the database, just saving a few more values within one loop. Nested arrays would be an more advanced approach, because it's harder to read. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/275421/how-to-get-all-images-and-their-thumbnails-from-wp-media-library Doing fine, thanks a lot, hope you do as well !

Comment: i know it has been a long time, but if you have any idea on how to get an excerpt it would mean a lot :D using get_the_excerpt($post->ID) doesnt work

Comment: Haha :D well get_the_excerpt is the right function to use. you can open another question and add your code. then post here in this question your link to the question so i get notified. i'm sure we will find a solution.

Comment: haha, yea, i am sorry but i really didnt know what to do :D
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61801121/html5blank-save-excerpt-into-array